# Define a generic type constraint to be of the same type as the implementation

Tags: c#, .net, class, generics, interface

I wonder if it is possible to force constraint on interface or abstract class generic type to be the same as the concrete class that implements it specially for it.

Lets say we want to check a fitness of certain entity to task and make it comparable to others in their proficiency

```
abstract class Entity
{
    public abstract int Fitness(); //Bigger the number - more fit the entity is

    public int MoreFitThan(Entity other)
    {
        return Fitness().CompareTo(other.Fitness());
    }
}

class Fish : Entity
{
    public int swimSpeed { get; set; }

    public override int Fitness()
    {
        return swimSpeed;
    }
}

class Human : Entity
{
    public int testPoints { get; set; }

    public override int Fitness()
    {
        return testPoints;
    }
}
```

But now we can compare fish's speed with human's test passing capability, which doesn't make sense.

```
static void Main()
        {
            Human human = new Human() {testPoints = 10};
            Fish fish = new Fish() { swimSpeed = 20 };
            fish.MoreFitThan(human);
        }
```

So is there a general way make some kind of class or interface that would force it's children classes to implement only own type to own type comparison? 
Like so we could only compare people with people and fish to fish, but without explicitly specifying the type of comparable entity?

Comment: "comparable to others in their proficiency" - what?

Answer (score 1):

You can force the type being passed to `MoreFitThan` to match the inheriting class by using generics in the following way.

```
abstract class Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>
{
    public abstract int Fitness(); //Bigger the number - more fit the entity is

    public int MoreFitThan(T other)
    {
        return Fitness().CompareTo(other.Fitness());
    }
}

class Fish : Entity<Fish>
{
    public int swimSpeed { get; set; }

    public override int Fitness()
    {
        return swimSpeed;
    }
}

class Human : Entity<Human>
{
    public int testPoints { get; set; }

    public override int Fitness()
    {
        return testPoints;
    }
}
```

Then the following would be a compilation error

```
Human human = new Human() {testPoints = 10};
Fish fish = new Fish() { swimSpeed = 20 };
fish.MoreFitThan(human);
```

because `Human` is not a `Fish`.  However this would allow a class that inherits from `Fish` to be compared to a `Fish`.

```
class Trout : Fish 
{
    public int size { get; set; }

    public override int Fitness()
    {
        return size;
    }
}
```

The following works because a `Trout` is a `Fish`.

```
Trout trout = new Trout() {size = 10};
Fish fish = new Fish() { swimSpeed = 20 };
fish.MoreFitThan(trout);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that it's legal to write `class Human : Entity<Fish>` which brings this solution back to the original problem, but at least it's in the hands of the library producer, and not the consumer, to follow the rules.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create classes of comparable types, say: `Swimmer`, `Runner`, `Learner` that implement your interface, then in those classes also implement `IComparable` and enforce the constraint on that class type. Then you can extend those classes with `Human` for `Learner`, `Fish` for `Swimmer`, etc...

There are other ways to do it, but this should work fine for your needs.